# Can you recognize the exact color bottles?

Tags: paint, painting, material-identification

Years ago I did a work, it was possible thanks to the colors, I retried to achieve the same effect but did not worked so far. I have only this low-resolution photo. And I don't remember the colors. Can you recognize some of the bottles in it? I need to order again (and this time I'll keep a notice with the manufaturer and color type information).

[image]

Comment: While id questions are on topic here, some additional information would be helpful- where on the planet are you? What type of paint is this (tempera, acrylic etc)... Which of the bottles? I see three distinct types. Please help us out as much as you can.

Comment: Italy, the long bottle is just too hided for identification. I'm still missing the gold bottle

Comment: I've closed this now for a couple reasons: 1) The picture is *really* blurry. 2) Your comment (and answer) indicate you're asking us to ID multiple, distinct objects and that's too broad for our format (even if the photo was clear)

Comment: sure no problem :). Picture is blurry but bottle labels most times have unique designs. Still need to identify the other 2 XD

Comment: Also, you are going through different mediums, photograph -> compression software -> computer screen, so there is no guarantee the colors we see are the ones you are after.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found!!

APA COLOR. Still missing the gold bottle.

[image]

Comment: You need to write an answer that actually supports itself with proof - a matching image, for example.

Comment: Thanks added. Actually it is not the same exact bottle, maybe they changed size. But the label is the same.